# inserting multiple rows in datatable using table in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm trying to insert multiple rows in a database taking input from table in JSP

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/SpringMVC/addStudent">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="name" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="id" /></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>


    </table>
</form:form>
```

actually number of rows could vary at runtime. Is there any way to achieve this? 
I am using spring mvc

Comment: Could you post what you have tried?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see how to post

Comment: You need to show us your controller for `/SpringMVC/addStudent`

Answer (score 0):

You tagged [java](/questions/tagged/java) but you don't show how you manage your beans...

Anyway, in order to achieve what you need use a [`<c:forEach>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_foreach_tag.htm) tag to get the desired number of rows, also you can keep values into an array, i.e:

```
<table>
    <c:forEach var="counter" begin="0" end="${numberOfRows}">
        <tr>
            <td><form:input path="names[${counter}]" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="ages[${counter}]" /></td>
            <td><form:input path="ids[${counter}]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </c:forEach>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @RequestMapping(value="/addStudent", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public String addStudent(@ModelAttribute("HelloWeb")Student student,ModelMap model)
 {
  model.addAttribute("name", student.getName());
  model.addAttribute("age", student.getAge());
  model.addAttribute("id", student.getId());
  studentDaoImp.create(student.getName(), student.getAge());
  return "StudentAdded";
 }

Comment: i dont know how to accept multiple rows from jsp and then insert it

Comment: if i take input as array names[${counter}] then how should i handle it in my controller. I am sorry i am new here so i dont have any idea

Comment: please update your question to clarify, also, to understand my code, change `end="${numberOfRows}"` to `end="5"`

Answer (score 0):

If your question is for how to build a UI for that then I think you can use JavaScript to dynamically add a row to the page using onClick events on a button !

Comment: Yes - i wanted to say one "can" use JavaScript. Changed my answer. Thanks !